# Problema com request post em um loop NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

estou com um problema em meu código e não consegui sair dele.
O que acontece é que faço uma request get ( que esta funcionando ) e pego o retorno dele que vem em formato JSON, após isso faço um for para percorrer meus dados e fazer uma inserção de dados via ( request post ), o problema está aí:

```js
async function intervalFunc() {
    console.log('Um minuto:');

    request('https://xxx/api/report/v1', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);

        (async () => {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
                console.log('dentro do for passou pelo id: ' + i);
                var val = obj.data[i];
                await inserirBrasil(val, i);

            }
        })()


    });

}
```

```js
async function inserirBrasil(val, i) {
    console.log('iserindo id ' + i + " "+val.uf);

    request.post('http://localhost:1111/api/brasil/', {
        data: { uid: val.uid, uf: val.uf, estado: val.state }
    }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            //console.error(error)
            return
        }
        //console.log('ok ', i);
        //console.log('res ', res);
        //console.log('body ', body);
    })

}
```

abaixo é o meu retorno de console:

```js
Um minuto:
error: null
statusCode: 200
dentro do for passou pelo id: 0
iserindo id 0 SP
dentro do for passou pelo id: 1
iserindo id 1 RJ
dentro do for passou pelo id: 2
iserindo id 2 CE
dentro do for passou pelo id: 3
iserindo id 3 DF
dentro do for passou pelo id: 4
iserindo id 4 MG
dentro do for passou pelo id: 5
iserindo id 5 SC
dentro do for passou pelo id: 6
iserindo id 6 RS
dentro do for passou pelo id: 7
iserindo id 7 BA
dentro do for passou pelo id: 8
iserindo id 8 PR
dentro do for passou pelo id: 9
iserindo id 9 AM
dentro do for passou pelo id: 10
iserindo id 10 PE
dentro do for passou pelo id: 11
iserindo id 11 ES
dentro do for passou pelo id: 12
iserindo id 12 GO
dentro do for passou pelo id: 13
iserindo id 13 MS
dentro do for passou pelo id: 14
iserindo id 14 AC
dentro do for passou pelo id: 15
iserindo id 15 SE
dentro do for passou pelo id: 16
iserindo id 16 RN
dentro do for passou pelo id: 17
iserindo id 17 MA
dentro do for passou pelo id: 18
iserindo id 18 MT
dentro do for passou pelo id: 19
iserindo id 19 AL
dentro do for passou pelo id: 20
iserindo id 20 TO
dentro do for passou pelo id: 21
iserindo id 21 PI
dentro do for passou pelo id: 22
iserindo id 22 PA
dentro do for passou pelo id: 23
iserindo id 23 PB
dentro do for passou pelo id: 24
iserindo id 24 RO
dentro do for passou pelo id: 25
iserindo id 25 RR
dentro do for passou pelo id: 26
iserindo id 26 AP
```

e dentro do post da minha api, eu coloquei um console.log(Object.keys(req).length)), resultado abaixo:

tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33
tamanho:  33

Em resumo, meu código mal feito esta enviando a requisição(com todos os estados juntos) todas as vezes que dou um post ( e que deveria ser um poste para cada estado ).
alguem poderia me da um suporte?

abaixo codigo no post da minha api

```js
exports.post = async (repositorio, validationContract, req, res) => {
    try {

        let data = req.body;
        if (!validationContract.isValid()) {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Existem dados inválidos na sua requisição.',
                validation: validationContract.errors()
            }).end();
            return;
        }

        let resultado = await repositorio.create(data);
        res.status(201).send(resultado);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Post com erro, motivo: ', err);
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Erro no processamento', error: err });
    }
}
```

Eu modifiquei o código abaixo mudando o tipo 'data' para 'json' e o codigo passou a inserir apenas os dois primeiros registros, não inserindo os demais.

```js
async function inserirBrasil(val, i) {
    console.log('iserindo id ' + i + " "+val.uf);

    request.post('http://localhost:1111/api/brasil/', {
        json: { uid: val.uid, uf: val.uf, estado: val.state }
    }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            //console.error(error)
            return
        }
        //console.log('ok ', i);
        //console.log('res ', res);
        //console.log('body ', body);
    })

}
```

Comment: Poderíamos ver o tratamento do POST na sua API? Porque se o *req* no seu *console.log* for o objeto request do Express, o erro está aí.

Comment: grato, adicionei ao código da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, modifiquei o tipo de parâmetro no 'request', modifiquei para 'form' e o problema foi resolvido.

```js
async function inserirBrasil(val, i) {
    console.log('iserindo id ' + i + " "+val.uf);

    request.post('http://localhost:1111/api/brasil/', {
        json: { uid: val.uid, uf: val.uf, estado: val.state }
    }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            //console.error(error)
            return
        }
        //console.log('ok ', i);
        //console.log('res ', res);
        //console.log('body ', body);
    })

}
```